# I would like to do a svn diff --summarize between to dev tags

Tags: svn

This is the command I typed:

```
svn diff --summarize --xml 7.x 8.4
```

and I get an error:

```
svn: E200007: Summarizing diff can only compare repository to repository
```

The directory paths are `/Users/apronest/subversion/DEV_TAGS/7.x` and `/Users/apronest/subversion/DEV_TAGS/8.4`

Answer (score 2):

Use URLs (which point at the repository) instead of local working copy paths, just like the error message implies.

`svn diff --summarize --xml $REPO/tags/7.x $REPO/tags/8.4` where `$REPO` is the URL to your repository root, probably something like `http://svn.example.com/svn/myproject`.  You can find this out by using the `svn info` command against your working copy.

Comment: Using `^` shorthand for repo-root (inside WC of the same repo, any node) may be prettier